# Serve Internet to remote machine via SSH?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling

This question is asked from few times but my setup is little different from other setup.

I have my machine sitting in closed network with no internet and I have sudo access to that machine. But I cant directly connect to my remote machine from my laptop. I have to go through a linux jump server and I dont have root permissions in the jump server. I can only ssh to my jump server and can again to ssh to my remote machine.

I cant have any other port opened. How can I share my internet connection of my laptop to my remote machine so that any updates or software pulls can happen seamlessly.

Currently when I have internet conenction to jump server I am able to share it with remote machine with command

```
ssh -R PORT_WITH_INTERNET:localhost:PORT_WITH_INTERNET user@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758935/serve-internet-to-remote-machine-via-ssh

Comment: `Currently when I have internet conenction to jump server I am able to share it with remote machine with command` You mean, you can currently share jump server's internet, but not laptop's internet?

Comment: @basin I got internet of some of other computer sitting in the closed network shred with jump server but anymore. That connection is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle), which:

> Transparent proxy server that works as a poor man's VPN. Forwards over ssh. Doesn't require admin. Works with Linux and MacOS. Supports DNS tunneling.

As long as your intermediate machine has Python installed `sshuttle` will connect, transfer itself, and set up your local machine to forward all traffic (or selected traffic) over the SSH connection.

The other nice thing is that it works with TCP rather than against it, so you get correct performance across the connection - regular SSH tunnels tend to get poor scaling because there's no packet loss.

You can use this straightforwardly to do what you want with:

```
sudo sshuttle --dns -r user@jump 0/0
```

This will connect over SSH to user@jump and forward all traffic and all DNS requests over that connection. You don't need to do any setup on the remote machine, and you only need administrative rights on your local machine (to set up the packet filtering rules).

`sshuttle` is packaged for some distributions, but it's very straightforward to install locally from [the git repository](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) with the standard Python `setup.py install` process. It's also in PyPI if you use that.

Comment: I cannot do ssh from remote machine to jump server. I can do ssh from my local to jump and from jump to remote. why would I want to forward the requests in my local to jump? shouldnt it be other way?

Comment: It seems that you ought to be able to SSH to the intermediate machine in both directions, and then use `-e` or ProxyCommand to jump out again, but if you can't then it doesn't directly help you, no. You can reverse-tunnel the traffic over any existing SSH connection but you do lose many of the advantages.

Answer (score 0):

If `ssh` on the jumpstation supports the '-W' argument, you can chain it:

In laptop's `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host 10.144.108.127
    ProxyCommand ssh -q user@jumpstation -W %h:%p
```

And in laptop's command line:

```
ssh -R PORT_WITH_INTERNET:localhost:PORT_WITH_INTERNET user@10.144.108.127
```

You also need to run a proxy on your laptop and set appropriate proxy settings on the remote machine.

Even if jumpstation ssh does not support the '-W' argument (which I doubt), that can be circumvented by calling `netcat` on the jumpstation or even opening `/dev/tcp/...` and a pair of `cat` (if you have bash there).